# Binary - Remove right-hand zeroes in a number

Tags: c#, binary, bit-shift

I can't figure out how I can remove right-hand zeros in a given binary number like this:

```
00110000 -> 11
1000 -> 1
```

According to my example, I know I can perform a right-shift of 4 and 3 to remove the unwanted zeros but I don't know how could I calculate the number of bits needed for the right-shift.

Comment: In what data type/format are you numbers stored? Integer, string, or something else?

Comment: @RossGurbutt Unsigned integers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
if (x != 0)
{
    while (x % 2 == 0)
        x = x >> 1;
}
```

It basically says keep bit shifting right whilst the number is even (doesn't have 1 as the right-most bit).

As mentioned in the comments by @Streamline, the loop alone won't work for a value of 0, so you have to check it's not 0 first.
No need to check every time round the loop for this though because if x != 0 then x >> n will never be 0 given the other looping condition that we stop when x % 2 != 0

If you need to know the number of bit-shifts, you can add a counter to the loop.
If you don't want to change the value of x, you can assign it to a temporary variable and use that instead.

Comment: Maybe you want to add a `x != 0` to the loop condition. Otherwise this will end in an endless loop.

Comment: Thanks @RossGurbutt and Streamline, problem solved! :)